# Portfolio variance over time vs. Portfolio variance from mix of two assets

Tags: equities, portfolio-management, statistics

Here are two facts about finance:

1.
If stock returns are not independent, for example tomorrow's return equals today's return, then the variance over two days will be less than the variance of 1day*2.  A test of market efficiency is that the variance over time does not decrease but is stable, meaning the returns are independent.
*Observation #1:When adding highly correlated observations, the combined will have a **lower** variance over the period.*

2.
When combining returns, the variance of the sum is equal to the sum of the variances and covariances Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)+2Cov(X,Y).  Therefore a portfolio of highly correlated observations will have the highest variance and one with negative correlation will have the lowest variance.
*Observation#2:When adding highly correlated observations, the combined will have a **higher** variance.*

What is wrong in my reasoning that Observation #1 and #2 are exactly opposite statements?
Is Observation #1 incorrect somehow?

Comment: (Positive) autocorrelation usually implies a higher variance.

Comment: Thanks! I think you are right-Simply my first statement was wrong..  Here is the quote that made me ask.  I now interpret it as noisy data would lead to negative autocorrelation and lower variance:.  French and Roll 1986 JFE: " If daily returns are independent, the variance for a long 
holding period will equal the cumulated daily variances within the period. 
However, if daily returns are affected by trading noise, the longer holding 
period variance wiIl be smaller than the cumulated daily variance"

Comment: The reason I was confused: Lets say there are 10 people in a room, instead of sampling all 10, I get lazy after sampling the second person and copy and paste their results 9 times, the resulting variance around the biased mean will be smaller